# Can not .map 2 different arrays in same table row, <tr>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map an entry to the table. In that entry, there is a column which can have more than one value.In that case, a sub-row will be created in the same row. I have attached an example below image. Here is the code I have tried which messes the table up completely.

```
{intake.map((value) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <th className="text-center" scope="row">{value}</th>
        </tr>
    )
})}
{attendanceIds.map((val, i) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td className="text-center">{date[i]}</td>
            <td className="text-center">{duration[i]}</td>
            <td className="text-center">{module[i]}</td>
            <td className="text-center">{start[i]}</td>
            <td className="text-center">{topic[i]}</td>
            <td className="text-center">{studentsPresent[i]}</td>
            <td className="text-center">{totalStudents[i]}</td>
            <td className="text-center"><button className="button" id={val}>Details</button></td>
        </tr>
    )
})}
```

[This is what I desire to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rmIQ.png)

[This is what I get from the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCuuT.png)

[This is the data I have. (One attendance ID has multiple intakes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMulQ.png)

Comment: is the intake map the same for each of the rows?

Comment: I've fixed your code formatting so the problem should be obvious - you output all the `intake` and then all the `attendanceIds` - seems you don't want to do that

Comment: @WillJenkins There can be multiple intakes for one row. So let's say a particular row can have multiple rows just for the intake column.

Comment: Are intakeMap and attendanceIds grouped together in your data?

Comment: can show the shape intake and attendanceIds data element

Comment: is there some way of identifying which `attendanceIds` belong to which `intake`

Comment: @WillJenkins See the edit, I have attached one more picture to show how the data is structured which I am trying to reflect.

Comment: "This is the data I have. (One attendance ID has multiple intakes)" - no, that's a PICTURE .. post data in the question instead if you want help

Comment: @JaromandaX No, any attendanceId can have any intake.

Comment: @JaromandaX I am fetching the data from firebase. How do I post this data here? These entries are in the variables provided in the code.

Comment: provide the array of both intake and attendanceIds shape and structure

Comment: the issue is, you've shown (in the picture which is useless) ONE attendanceID with its two intakes - and the code suggests you have two different things, rather than an array of intakes inside an array of attendanceID's ... I'd look at inverting your logic and nesting the maps

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, that is the logic. One AttendanceID can have 1 or more intakes. That is what I desire to output in the table. I have coded it incorrectly. But even if I nest arrays, it does not reflect clearly. Any opinions how exactly I should nest the arrays?

Answer (score 1):

The data looks like it belongs on the same row semantically, so you shouldn't use a new row, you should add your multiple entries as e.g. `div` (or whatever suits) in your `<td>`. Then use CSS to style as required.

From your question, it isn't entirely clear what your data structure is in your component, but assuming your attendanceIds map in the way that your image shows, you can do something like this:

```
{attendanceIds.map((val, i) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td className="text-center">{
                  val.intake.length === 1 
                         ? {val.intake[0]}
                         : val.intake.map(item=>
                               <div>{item}</div>)
                         }
            }</td>
            // add the rest of the <td>s here
        </tr>
    )
})}
```

(Note that I've left the rest of the mapping up to you as the way you've done it isn't clear to me.)

Comment: If I use your code, it gives a "Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","" at the line "? {val.intake}"

Comment: well it was only pseudo-code really... It's hard to know what the same of your attendanceIds array is like from what you've posted.